# Identifying meta tag standards across commonly used meta vocabularies

Tags: attributes, metadata, meta-tags, vocabulary

While attempting to identify various standards concerning meta-tags (and data) I have had very little (to no) luck in doing so. Fundamentally, my aim is to identify an area, organization, or site throughout the Internet that offers a **comprehensive** listing of all of the *current* (*i.e., non-deprecated*) meta-attribute types and keywords (*i.e., name, http-equiv, itemprop, etc…*) in conjunction with their individualized data-types, format, and delimiter tokens, as well as whether the tag (in question) should be self-closed or not. For example:

```
Tag:
     <meta name="keywords" content="key0,key1,key2">
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Breakdown:

     <meta

         name=       <= attribute-type 
         ”keywords”  <= “keyword”

         content=“   <= attribute-value
         key0        <= string data-type
         ,           <= comma delimiter
         key1        <= string data-type
         ,           <= comma delimiter
         ""          <= etc...

     />              <= recommended self-closing bracket
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

or

```
Tag:
     <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30;URL='http://domain.com/">

----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Breakdown:

     <meta

         http-equiv= <= attribute-type 
         ”refresh”   <= “keyword”

         content=“   <= attribute-value
         30          <= integer (or number) data-type
         ;           <= semi-colon delimiter
         URL=        <= attribute (optional)
        'http://..' <= URL format expected

     />              <= recommended self-closing bracket
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Naturally, I've scrubbed the web for days with little success. Albeit, *schema.org*, *metatags.org*, and the *WHATWG communities living HTML standard* concerning microdata encoding (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/#toc-microdata) have been the best sources towards assisting me in identifying the currently recommend standards and usage, there are a myriad of other resources that offer conflicting data, outdated information, and do not include the other common meta *vocabulary standards* used throughout the web, such as **DublinCore**, **OpenGraph**, etc… If anyone could assist me in pointing me in the right direction, I would surely appreciate it, and if not, then I appreciate at least appreciate you taking the time to read this request.

- Thanks and cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specifically care about `meta` elements, these two registries might be of help:

- https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions
- https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/PragmaExtensions

Coupled with the [HTML Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/) they should provide a pretty exhaustive view of that element.